# Unable to install "connect-mongo" npm package

Tags: javascript, database, npm-install, connect-mongo, mongoatlas

In order to use **Mongo-Session-Store**, I needed to install **"connect-mongo" npm package** to use in my project to ** use sessions through Mongo Atlas**. But its not getting installed due to **version incompatibility of another npm packages such as "cloudinary"** - a cloud based service platform.

[Terminal eror](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JlfK7.png)
[package.json file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OxqcT.png)

I tried changing versions of the indicated packages. Also I tried to install it forcibly by commands such as npm install connect-mongo --force and npm install connect-mongo --legacy-peer-deps, but still its not getting installed.